# javascript 'for loop' code completion in Webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Usually **CTRL-SPACE** does a lot of code completion actions in Webstorm. However I can't seem to find any quick code generation for 'for' loops.

I want something analogous to this :

[image]

Is there some reason Webstorm doesn't have this? Or has my googling been off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can type `itin` + `ctrl+space` and your loop template will be generated.
In the autocomplete window you will see a lamp, click in it to edit you template.

Here are some examples: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/javascript-postfix-completion/ and http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/high-speed-coding-with-custom-live-templates/

Comment: But one must be drunk to type "itin" when "for" was meant.

Comment: @feeela It's weird, but you can create your own "live template" with `for` in the "Settings/Live Templates" menu

Comment: @feela yeah 'itin' is weird. In Intellij for java its 'iter' isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Please see Settings/Editor/Live Templates, javascript - there are some snippets for different for loops generation

Comment: can't see 'Live Templates'. Is this a WS9 thing? I'm using WS8

Comment: it is Settings/Live Templates in WebStorm 8